# Thymeleaf th:each with javascript DOM manipulation causes strange error

Tags: javascript, html, dom, thymeleaf

I've got a simple Thymeleaf th:each loop looking like this:

```
<div class="list-group-item" th:each="scenarioList, scenarioIndex : ${allScenarios}">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block" th:id="'path_'+${scenarioIndex.index}">Button</button>
  .
  .
  .  
</div>
```

I need to give the buttons proper innerTexts in Javascript function, because some splicing needs to be done. It looks something like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var allScenarios =  /*[[${allScenarios}]]*/ null;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            var path = allScenarios[i].path;
            path = path.slice(0, path.lastIndexOf('\\'));
            document.getElementById("path_" + i).innerText = path;
        }
        /*]]>*/
</script>
```

And now a strange thing happens. Only the first and the last buttons innerTexts are set. All of the others are left with default "Button" text. When I try to manually set the innerText of the buttons in javascript console on my browser same thing happens - I can set first and last buttons text, but not the middle ones. When I check in the console what is the middle buttons innerText it seems to be correctly set by javascript function, but is not displaying at the webpage.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code at first glance, though I just took a glance. Can you post the HTML and Javascript that gets generated by the Thymeleaf code? And maybe step through the Javascript in your browser's debugger to confirm what it's trying to set?

Comment: First button:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block" id="path_0">.\conf\</button>`
Second button:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block" id="path_1">Button</button>`
So they actually look the same. Then in js console:
`document.getElementById("path_0").innerText = "test";`. First button gets changed.
`document.getElementById("path_1").innerText = "test";`. Second button doesn't get changed... It's really strange behaviour.